# VBA sorting cell color with varying ranges and sheets

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am currently learning/messing around with VBA coding so I could write some macros for work. I could really use some help please.

Question: I want the code below (which was written by macros recorder) to add some specific codes for my needs.

```
Sub Sort()

    Range("A1:D23").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A2:A23"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlDescending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
        255, 0)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:D23")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

End Sub
```

1. The first line I would like it not to be static with specific range. Would substituting `Range("A1:D23").Select` for `Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select` work for the varying ranges in my data tables?
2. For lines 3, 4 and 5 where it says `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8")`, how can I make it so that its active not only for sheet8 but for any sheet I open or create?
3. Finally on line 4 `Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A2:A23")`, I would like to change to the varying row amounts under that column from varying data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

1. Get how many rows your sheet has and work with it. See below for more information. Beware: it may be glitchy if the sheet is empty.
2. Replace `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 8")` with `ActiveSheet`. Unfortunately, ActiveSheet does not provide autocomplete, but it is a Sheet object. Casting it to any Sheet object would give you that behavior.
3. Well, once you want your code to deal with the same range twice, you might as well save it in a variable.

Considering your table may expand in rows and columns, you need to count them using the `End` command.

Here's the updated code:

```
Sub Sort()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim rngSort As Range
    Dim rngTable As Range
    Set sht = ActiveSheet        

    rowCount = sht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    Set rngSort = sht.Range("A1:A" & rowCount)
    Set rngTable = sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 1), sht.Cells(rowCount, 1).End(xlToRight))

    sht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    sht.Sort.SortFields.Add(rngSort, _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlDescending, , _
        xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

    With sht.Sort
        .SetRange rngTable
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Take a look at my range. I use `sht.Range` because when you don't say where your range is, Excel assumes it is your selected sheet. If it isn't you must explicitly say so. In your case, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you very much the help. One issue Set rng = sht.Range(Cells(1, 1), Range(Cells(1, 1)).End(xlDown) comes back with the compile error expected: list error or )

Comment: Sorry about that, but I don't have Excel currently installed to debug it. Will change the answer to a simpler approach.

Comment: Thanks for you patience, I am truly new at all this.

Comment: No problem. :) Updated my answer. Did it work? EDIT: just noticed that your table contains more than one column. My code needs a little update yet again.

Comment: Yeah my practice sheet has 4 columns, but that will change with the spreadsheet I use at work.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.datawright.com.au/excel_resources/excel_vba_selection.htm. It explains a lot of ways to select stuff. In the end, knowing how to get what you need in VBA is the most important part. And if my answer suits your needs, please check it as the accepted answer. :)

Comment: Oh man I don't want to annoy you or discourage you, so forgive me. But for line: Set rngTable = sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 1), sht.Cells(RowCount, 1).End(xlRight)) the error run time error '1004' aplication-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Don't worry. I installed Excel here and debugged the code. It turned out to be only a typo. I was trying to use `xlRight` instead of `xlToRight`. Tested here and it works now.

Comment: How can I do the same in C#? Tried the following: `oSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add(oRng, XlSortOn.xlSortOnCellColor, XlSortOrder.xlDescending, Type.Missing, Type.Missing).SortOnValue = XlRgbColor.rgbLightPink;` but I got an error: `Property or indexer 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.SortField.SortOnValue' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`